# Reputation tally in profile counts -1 for downvotes but not +1 for deleted downvotes

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

The profile page shows a number for the total reputation change since you last looked at that tab.  This number seems to include the -1s for downvotes you cast but *not* the +1s if those posts are later deleted, even though both events show up as highlighted:

[image: screen shot]

The total rep change from the highlighted events is 65; the number in the tab header is 64.  I've seen this consistently across several sites for a while, including MSE with the new Activity page; it's not new or localized behavior.

It's easy enough to figure out what's really going on, but the discrepancy stands out.  Can we make the number in the tab header match reality?

(The deletion didn't immediately follow the downvote, though it was on the same day.  So I don't think I should blame caching.  Besides, I *think* I've seen these for cases where the events occurred on different days.)

Comment: I think this affects the top bar display too, but it's been a while.

Comment: -1s from your own downvotes don't change the green number but show up in the list. +1s from deletion of those answers do change the green number but don't show up in the list (there's an MSE post about that somewhere).  This is yet another permutation: +1s do show up in the list but don't affect the tab header.  I suspect there's some rep-event-management code that could be refactored to share common code...

Comment: If I downvote someone and then get an upvote, my green number up top says +9.  There was a point in time where +1s from when downvoted posts were removed didn't update the top bar, but I don't know if that's still the case as most people I downvote haven't deleted their posts.  It's different code but I thought there might be a related bug.

Comment: Oh that's true; -1s are reflected in the green number if there's a bigger change in the other direction.  If you just DV, no change; if you then gain rep, 1 is subtracted when that number is reported.